# How do I get word embedding using CoreNlp from Stanford?

Tags: java, vectorization, stanford-nlp, word-embedding

I am using CoreNlp to get the information extraction from a large text. However, its using the "triple" approach where a single sentence produce many output which is good, but there are some sentences that doesn't make sense. I tried to eliminate this by running another unsupervised NLP and try to utilize function in CoreNlp, yet I stuck at getting word vector form CoreNlp. Can anyone point where do I need to start searching for codes that do the word embedding in CoreNlp? Also I am newbie in java and IT.

There are some open libraries like glove, word2vec, text2vec, but I noticed glove already been used in CoreNlp (correct me if wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since training your own model from scratch might turn out to be a time-consuming task, you could just download pretrained vectors from:
https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/

however, there is an example with dl4j here that might do to trick:
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/nlp/glove/GloVeExample.java